# R, how do i create a string with the information of a table?

Tags: r

I have this table:

```
 > equiposcount

   MOVIL     PILA PORTATIL 
     138        1       13
```

and I would like to create a string such as the following:

```
"138 MOVIL, 1 PILA, 13 PORTATIL"
```

I am a little lost here, since

```
> names(equiposcount)
[1] "MOVIL"    "PILA"     "PORTATIL"
```

is of type character and not a vector.
Can anyone help me with this? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can either `stack` it to `data.frame`, `paste` the columnns ('values', 'ind') together with the arguments `sep` and `collapse`

```
with(stack(equiposcount), paste(values, ind, sep=" ", collapse=", "))
#[1] "138 MOVIL, 1 PILA, 13 PORTATIL"
```

---

Or directly use `paste` on the `names` of the named vector and the vector itself

```
paste(equiposcount, names(equiposcount), sep=" ", collapse=", ")
#[1] "138 MOVIL, 1 PILA, 13 PORTATIL"
```

#### data

```
equiposcount <- c(MOVIL = 138, PILA = 1, PORTATIL = 13)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `Map` function-

```
> paste(Map(paste,equiposcount,names(equiposcount)),collapse = ",")
[1] "138 MOVIL,1 PILA,13 PORTATIL"
```